# Get file directory from function file python

Tags: python

Say my directory looks like this

```
folder
⮑ file.py
⮑ class.py
```

In want to make a function in class.py that can return the filepath of the current file when it is executed in file.py.
I have tried `__file__` and `os.path.basename/dirname/abspath` but they return the filepath of class.py when I want the filepath of file.py.

How can I get the filepath of file.py from class.py's function?

Comment: Is `class.py` doing `import file`?  If so, then you can do `file.__file__`.  If you're talking about the other way around, then there is no way.  A file can be imported from many places.  You can pass the location when you CALL functions in `class`.

Comment: Sorry, ```file.py``` is importing ```class.py``` which has the function that should get the filename.

Comment: Then you'll have to pass it as a parameter.  Remember that functions get called long after the import is finished, and the functions can even be called from files that didn't do the import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the following in your function in `class.py`.

```
import inspect
filename = inspect.stack()[1].filename
```